# Removing an item from a list without removing it from its datasource - c#

Tags: c#, listbox, datasource

I'm trying to remove an item from a listBox after i have drag and dropped it, but when i do so i got a message saying i cant modify the listbox since its linked with a datasource.

The thing is that i want to remove the item only from the view of the listBox while keeping it in the datasource.

Here is what i have tried to do:

```
int indexSelec = listBox3.SelectedIndex;

listBox3.Items.Remove(listBox3.Items[indexSelec]);
```

Does anybody has a solution?

Thx

Answer (score 0):

You should storage List Box items to **List< string >** then use that List to add or remove items from List Box. Here is example:

First add a new list: `List<string> _items = new List<string>();`

Now add items to list and display it on List Box:

```
_items.Add("One");
_items.Add("Two");
_items.Add("Three");
listBox1.DataSource = _items; //this will display added items to  List Box
```

Adding items to List Box:

```
_items.Add("New Item " + DateTime.Now.Second);
listBox1.DataSource = null;
listBox1.DataSource = _items;
```

Removing items from List Box:

```
int selectedIndex = listBox1.SelectedIndex;
try
{
    _items.RemoveAt(selectedIndex);
}
catch
{
}
listBox1.DataSource = null;
listBox1.DataSource = _items;
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot remove the `ListBoxItem` from the `ListBox`, because it is part of a `ReadOnlyCollection`.

But you can set its `Visibility`.

```
ListBoxItem c = (ListBoxItem) ListBox1.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(ListBox1.Items[0]);

c.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed;
```